# Qt drawPixmap isn't drawing what I expect

Tags: c++, qt, paint, qpixmap

I'm trying to make a Paint application in C++ with Qt. Everytime I click or click & drag the mouse, the program will draw something on a pixmap. After that, it updates the window calling paintEvent(), which will draw the pixmap onto the window.

```
void QPaintArea::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
    startpoint = event->pos();
    drawPoint(startpoint);
    is_pressed = true;
}

void QPaintArea::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
    is_pressed = false;
}

void QPaintArea::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
    if(is_pressed == true){
        endpoint = event->pos();
        drawLine(startpoint, endpoint);
        startpoint = endpoint;
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
}

void QPaintArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event){
    QDesktopWidget *desktop = QApplication::desktop();
    int x = (desktop->width() - 800) / 2;
    int y = (desktop->height() - 600) / 2;
    QPainter painter(this);
    QRect target(QPoint(x, y - 35), QSize(800, 600));
    QRect dirtyrect(QPoint(0,0), QSize(800, 600));
    painter.drawPixmap(target, *pixmap, dirtyrect);
}
```

The problem is that, the program is not printing the pixmap onto the window as expected. For example, I press the mouse at x: 17, y: 82 trying to draw something. The program will print what I drew but at an offset location, like x + 20, y.

Maybe I don't fully understand how QRect or drawPixmap works, but the pixmap is 800x600. "dirtyrect" is supposed to save the entire pixmap (starting a x: 0, y: 0, and the size 800x600).

Comment: What is QPaintArea, remember that event position is relative to widget, so if you have for example some margins, then your pixmap position is 0+margin-left,0+margin-top

Comment: QPaintArea is the window, the class created by me.

Comment: Just a hint, but keep Q prefix for Qt, you should choose other for you :). Did you setup any layout within it?

Comment: Well, QPaintArea is an widget. I created another QMainWindow as the window and use setCentralWidget().

Comment: Where did you get all those magic numbers? Why do you paint pixmap on some calculated x,y of your QPaintArea? You realize that for painter QPoint(0,0) is widgets top left corner?

Comment: Isn't QPixmap just a pure virtual image, and it has nothing to do with the window ? QPoint(0, 0) with a size of 800x600 is the entire pixmap. I take the entire pixmap and draw it onto a portion of my window, which has the same size(800x600).

Comment: Your paintEvent would use a point relative to that widget. 0,0 would be the corner of the QPaintArea. Im not sure why you need all the desktop math. I agree with Kamil. It seems like a bunch of magic numbers

Answer (score 3):

drawPixmap(target, pixmap, source) paints on target rect of painter area (QPaintArea in this case) source part of pixmap. So you paint whole pixmap (0,0,800,600) at some (x,y-35,800,600) rect of QPaintArea. If you want to paint whole pixmap on whole QPaintArea just use drawPixmap(QPoint(0,0), *pixmap).

// EDIT

But if you expected, that pixmap will be painted with some offset from QPaintArea top left corner, then your calculations are wrong, and if you wont explain what did you want to achieve we won't be able to help you. Explain us your calculations of x,y (and magic -35 for y), and maybe we will be able to figure something out

// EDIT
You don't have to use window offsets like -35 if you're painting on widget. 0,0 of the widget is not top left corner of window frame, but of widget contents. How do you expect it to behave on other platforms?

If you want to paint it in the middle of your window simply use:

```
void QPaintArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event){
    QPoint middle = geometry.center();
    int x = middle.x() - 800/2; // probably best would be pixmap->width()/2
    int y = middle.y() - 600/2; // probably best would be pixmap->height()/2
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawPixmap(QPoint(x,y), *pixmap);
}
```

Comment: I want to draw the pixmap at a rectangle at the center of the window. x and y are the coordinantes. My program's window is set at full screen, so program's window's size is equal to desktop size. I take the desktop size, decrease the pixmap size and divide it by 2. -35 for y is because i toke the desktop's size, not my program window's size, so i need to decrease for menu-bars and other things. I want to draw the pixmap somewhere at the center of the window.

Comment: I tried that, and it works, thanks. But the program have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Then you're doing something else wrong. This code will paint pixmap in the middle of available widget space. I won't gues what, as clearly you should sit down and separate problem. Maybe start from not using QMainWindow at all...